# Subdomains not working on Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain

I would like to have a subdomain (webmail.inkieweb.com) for my website which points to the same folder as www.inkieweb.com/webmail (/var/www/webmail/), but whenever I access the subdomain, I'm instantly redirected to inkieweb.com (/var/www/) instead. This is bothering me as some of my clients are requesting subdomains and I have no idea why they're not working.

EDIT: I was previously working with a CNAME. I removed that and added an "A" record instead. Now it's not redirecting. It is still loading /var/www/ instead of /var/www/webmail/ though.

These are what I think are the relevant files on my server: http://pastebin.com/Gf6ZSjPv

Note that even though the last two files have the full hostname in the `<VirtualHost inkieweb.com:80>` section, I have also tried having everything with *:80 instead. Still nothing.

The only thing that happens sometimes is that when I'm messing around with `a2ensite` and `a2dissite`, instead of loading the home page, http://www.inkieweb.com starts loading the webmail instead.

Please help me. I don't know what else I can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you get any errors when you start up apache?  Things like inkieweb.com has no virtualhosts?

Are there any virtualhosts defined in your httpd.conf file that may be overriding the one your working with?

I would stick with the *:80 and make sure your have serveraliases for each one that make sense and that the server aliases are not overlapping.  You can use grep to find all of them.

Comment: * Starting web server apache2                                                  [Fri Dec 06 14:42:08 2013] [warn] VirtualHost inkieweb.com:80 overlaps with VirtualHost webmail.inkieweb.com:80, the first has precedence, perhaps you need a NameVirtualHost directive
[Fri Dec 06 14:42:08 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
                                                                         [ OK ]

Comment: I would go back to the *:80 virtualhost and get rid of the startup errors then start tracing down what is going on.

Comment: Thank you for your time.

httpd.conf is completely empty

I removed all virtualhost files and left `default`. When I reload apache2 now I only get `[warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts`

Where do I go now?

Comment: Do you have a <virtualhost *:80> in one of your config files?  If you change your inkieweb.com to * you should be close.  Then you just need to get the servernames and serveraliases sorted out.  The * just means all ip addresses.    http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: I honestly don't know what I'm doing wrong, mate. 

Okay, so I found NameVirtualHost in post.conf and I commented it out.

Now I'm getting no errors.

But whenever I try to follow the steps in your link, (i.e. bunch of VirtualHost tags with *:80) I get the precedence warning and, regardless of the subdomain I'm using, the website loads the FIRST virtual host.

I also grepped for any virtual hosts remaining and found only one (the one in the default).

Comment: virt hosts are confusing at first and can be frustrating to debug.  But they are very useful.  If you only have a single ip you may want to put that in rather than the *.  I don't know why but that has helped me find problems in the past.  When you have a hundred of them with wildcard domains it gets even worse trying to figure out is overriding what.

Comment: So apparently I needed to add a NameVirtualHost line for each one of my subdomains and then the VirtualHost tags could be turned into `<VirtualHost inkieweb.com:80>` and `<VirtualHost webmail.inkieweb.com:80>`. Thanks for taking the time mate. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Good deal.  The latest version of apache does away with the Namevirtualhost thing so that makes it a bit simpler.